# Domain of dependence for Hyperbolic system of PDES

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, cauchy-problem

In Leveque's "Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws", Ch. 3.1.1., he says that given a system of Hyperbolic PDE's and a point $(\bar{t},\bar{x} )$, its domain of dependence $D(\bar{t},\bar{x} )$ is always a bounded set. The domains of dependence here is defined by the minimal size of an initial data set needed to determine the solution's value at a given point.

**My question:** Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation#Definition) hyperbolicity of a system by its eigenvalues. How can I proceed from this definition to prove the boundedness of the domain of dependence?

Thanks

Comment: (1) Leveque's use of the word "domain of dependence" is non-standard, usually one refers to the entire space-time domain and not just its intersection with the initial data hypersurface. (2) This result is old and standard (going back to at least Leray), for strictly or symmetric hyperbolic systems; look for example in Volume 2 of Courant-Hilbert where they discuss hyperbolic PDEs. (3) The property you are referring to is also called the "finite speed of propagation" property for hyperbolic PDEs, and is proven in most textbooks in hyperbolic PDEs.

Comment: For the sake of giving a reasonably complete reference: the case of strictly hyperbolic systems with variable coefficients is treated by Jean Leray in his notes on [Hyperbolic Differential Equations](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=63548); for first order hyperbolic systems, you can see [this article by Rauch](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2254010) and his references.

Comment: As Willie mentioned, the domain of dependence theorem is discussed in many textbooks and monographs (see the answers to [MO181630](http://mathoverflow.net/q/181630/2622) for a sample of references). Of course, there are many (slightly distinct) notions of hyperbolicity and the proof needs to be adapted to each case.

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks, here's a full link to Rauch's paper - http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.maa/1175797445

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: do you know which of the items in your list deal with the case of higher order hyperbolic systems? (Leray is the only one I checked since it was the only one I had in my office; I know also that several on your list only treat first/second order equations.)

Comment: @WillieWong, if by higher order you just mean _wave-like_ (aka _normally hyperbolic_, that is with a principal symbol given by the metric tensored with a diagonal matrix) systems, then the books with "wave" in the title do, as well as Courant-Hilbert, Christodoulou and a few other ones. Though, I'm not sure if any of them has a thorough discussion of systems of higher order equations (except maybe Leray). Such a discussion is actually hard to find and is always very technical.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: no, I actually mean 3rd, 4th, arbitrary $n$th order PDE systems. I'm curious whether anyone since Leray had thought of treating these systems systematically.

Comment: @WillieWong, ah, then one modern reference that I know is Volevich & Gindikin, _Mixed problem for partial differential equations with quasihomogeneous principal part_ (AMS, 1996) [MR1357662](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1357662). But it's so technical, that I never managed to really sink my teeth into it.